# Did Henry Simmons play the dealer in Agents of Shield S06 E03?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, casting, agents-of-shield

In Agents of Shield, S06 E03, Fitz plays a variation of blackjack in a space casino. The dealer looks a lot like a heavily made-up Henry Simmons (the actor who plays Mack). Is it him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This character's name is [Montalban](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Montalban). According to [IMDB credits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8416904/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) he's played by [Ski Carr](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0139858/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t17).